# How can I add a background image in react native so that it takes the whole height of the screen but only part of the width?

Tags: android, image, react-native

I have tried using the ImageBackground element with different resize options, but I was not able to achieve the required result. I want to make it look like the image on the right.
Disclaimer: I am new to React Native so there might be sth that I have missed..

Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
<ImageBackground resizeMode='stretch' style={{ flex:1 }} source={image} imageStyle={{ marginLeft: '50%'}}>
```

Comment: it does put the picture where it's supposed to be, but since I have the ImageBackground as a wrapper element of my whole content, the content shrinks as well. I have no idea where to position the ImageBackground so it does not interfere with the layout.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it helped. Please mark the answer as useful for future generations.